# Create delay in ActionScript 3 function

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flex4

I have a function in Adobe Flex 4 (ActionScript 3) that accepts an object and returns an ArrayCollection...

If a certain global variable is set to true, I want the function to delay itself for 3 seconds before running.  Otherwise I want the function to run as normal.

The problem is, if I use a Timer, that timer calls a *separate* function, and that function cannot return anything to my calling function, nor can the function it calls accept any parameters, so it's not like I can call my own function recursively after the TimerComplete event fires...  And a recursive call wouldn't work anyway, because it would return the ArrayCollection to the timer-result function, not to the original calling function...

I need a delay *within* the function, not a delay that causes me to go outside that function.  But I cannot figure out how to do it.

Something like this is what I need to do:

```
private function createArrayCollection(myObject:Object):ArrayCollection {

    var myArrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    if (globalWaitBoolean) {
        //delay here for 3 seconds, somehow
    }

    //Here I do the stuff that uses the info in myObject to figure out what to
    //put into the ArrayCollection I want to return

    return (myArrayCollection);
}
```

So...  Any ideas on how to accomplish this without calling an external Timer function that cannot return an object back to my original function?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The way you want it you will have your whole application to lag for 3 seconds, unresponsive to any user input and external events. But it is possible, sure:

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;

private function createArrayCollection(myObject:Object):ArrayCollection
{
    var myArrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

    if (globalWaitBoolean)
    {
        var waitUntil:int = getTimer() + 3000;

        // Method getTimer() returns time in ms passed since app start.
        // So you just have to wait until it is greater than appointed time.
        while (getTimer() < waitUntil)
        {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }

    return (myArrayCollection);
}
```

Still, if you want to do it in a **correct** way of doing it:

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

private function callerMethod():void
{
    // Blah blah blah.
    // ...
    // Finally.
    createArrayCollection(sourceData, asyncResult);
}

private function createArrayCollection(myObject:Object, handler:Function):void
{
    var result:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

    if (globalWaitBoolean) setTimeout(handler, 3000, result);
    else handler(result);
}

private function asyncResult(source:ArrayCollection):void
{
    // The rest of your processing code.
}
```

Comment: Yes, the correct way, unfortunately, cannot be done because the caller program is an Adobe AIR program that I cannot change without updating it on many hundreds of client machines -- and the function that program is calling is inside a "module" that only one client is having an issue with, so it's far easier to modify the module for the one client than it is to modify the AIR app for hundreds of clients.  Therefore, I need this ridiculous, incorrect-programming-practices hack to make it work just for this one client.  Thanks so much for your reply -- it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh -- FYI, if I add a line that says this.ValidateNow() inside the while loop, I think it might actually allow interaction with the program while it's waiting for the timer to go by.  I'm going to try that, at least, and see what happens.  Even if it locks the program up for 3 seconds, it's only one client that will be experiencing this issue, and only every once in a while.

Comment: @LaurenceMacNeill No, it will not. Flash application has a single execution thread for AS3 script, so it won't do anything else while traversing this empty loop.

Answer (score 1):

Normal (synchronous) code flow would not return until the value is prepared, so should you desire to actually wait for 3 seconds while not allowing your app to do anything, use `getTimer()` approach from @Organis's answer. If you'll go for an asynchronus result, you'll need to face and overcome some more problems.

First, when do you expect your returned `ArrayCollection` to actually arrive. Speaking of code design, asynchronous code requires a whole lot of assumptions, thread safety etc etc, and even while AS3/Flash does not have true multithreading unless you count `Worker`s, the code flow with events is not as obvious. So, whoever called your `createArrayCollection()` MUST NOT expect value returned from it right away. So, speaking about your direct question, **NO, you can't avoid timers of some sort if you desire a responsive application. But you can use them with an approach that would involve an indirectly returned result.**

Second, whether there might be concurring requests for more array collections from objects if your app would require these - you have to prepare for any kind of interference that might be caused by this. Say your function is triggered by a button click - what if that button would get clicked more than once in 3 seconds?

Third, actual route to processing code is not direct with asynchronous return. You need either a callback, an event handler (which is essentially a semi-native callback), a code that periodically checks for value presence (enter frame handler, etc) or a similar trick to gather the value that's returned asynchronously, and then transfer it to any relevant code that would process it further. Therefore, you would need to design an interface capable of receiving complex data (source object forward, array collection backward) and then carefully test it against all the possible cases and flaws.

An example of implementing all that is very long, I'll try to outline it somehow. Ler's assume you have a sort of "server" class that accepts requests for data and processes it synchronously (no wait) or asynchronously (wait). It accepts a source object of type "T" and provides a newly created object of type `ArrayCollection`, supplied as a parameter to whatever callback function sent to it. Also it accepts a delay (a simple way to show sync/async return would be a boolean, but why not getting an int?) as a parameter, and guarantees (to the extent of event model limitations) that after this delay the callback will be called ASAP. The architecture will then look like this:

```
class Processor {
    Dictionary requests; // here all the requests that are delayed will be stored
    public function dpr(source:T,callback:Function,delay:int=0):void{...}
    // creates requests and stores them
    private function syncProcess(source:T):ArrayCollection {...}
    // whatever routine you want to get variably delayed
    private function processTimeout(e:Event=null):void {...}
    // processes events from "setTimeout()" and calls callbacks
}
```

Note that asynchronous approach forced to create three more entities than a synchronous one. First is the request holding structure (the dictionary here), second is timeout event handler, third is whatever callback you'll desire to get called when the data is ready. The code flow would go like this:

Synchronous call would result in the callback directly called from within the class: `request`->`processTimeout`->`syncProcess()`->`callback`. Asynchronous call will have the callback called from within `Timer::timerComplete` event handler via `setTimeout` called within `request`, with data that originally came from `request` stored in `requests`.

Comment: It's an Adobe AIR app that is calling the function, which is contained inside a Flex "module" that the AIR app loads.  The AIR app is *supposed* to wait until it gets the ArrayCollection back before it does anything else.  The module creates print-jobs, and one of those print-jobs *might* be an envelope, which takes longer than a regular print-job. And if I don't stop the process and make it wait for the envelope to print, Windows will happily store that print job for a good long time, and print it after several more jobs have gone by -- thus making everything out-of-order. I don't know why.

Comment: And, yes, stopping everything to wait for a stupid envelope to print is a total hack job.  But at this point, I've exhausted everything else I can think of.  It's a Windows problem, and I have almost no control from inside my Flex "module" over anything that Windows does, unfortunately.

Comment: Hm-m-m. Printing with AS3 is what I have never really done, and yes, there can be issues. I wonder however, if you can really split jobs in your AS3 app so that your normal jobs would go first, then you delay that envelope if it's present, show up a popup like "Click when ready" and then send that envelope to printer?

Comment: No, unfortunately the envelopes have to print in order with the other stuff -- the envelopes are used as "separators", so to speak.  An envelope for a given account prints, then all of the tickets/badges/etc print for that same account, then the envelope for the next account, followed by badges/tickets/etc for that account, etc, etc.  We typically do 500 to 1,000 accounts at a time.  The envelopes *must* print in the proper order with the badges/tickets/etc to facilitate stuffing and mailing them.  If anything gets out of order, it's a major headache.

Comment: Maybe then you should approach the problem from the other end, monitor the print queue from AS3 side via callbacks or other API, then send a job with envelope to printing, wait until it completes, then resume printing normal stuff until the next envelope?

Comment: I never have been able to figure out how to make Windows talk to my AIR app...  That's definitely the "best practices" way to do it -- get Windows to tell the app when to proceed, rather than just guessing how long I have to stop the app to wait for printing to finish.  But Windows and AIR and Flex don't all get along very well, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an embedded/inline function:

```
private function createArrayCollection(myObject:Object):ArrayCollection {

    var myArrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    if (globalWaitBoolean) {
        var milliseconds:int = 3000;
        //delay here for 3 seconds
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            //Here I do the stuff that uses the info in myObject to figure out what to
            //put into the ArrayCollection I want to return
            return (myArrayCollection);
        },
        milliseconds);
    }
    else
    {
        //Here I do the stuff that uses the info in myObject to figure out what to
        //put into the ArrayCollection I want to return
        return (myArrayCollection);
    }
}
```

The inner function will have access to all local vars of the outer function.